# NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException when injecting JpaRepository to Generic class

Tags: java, generics, spring-boot, autowired

How to inject repository to generic class?

```
public class FruitComboBox<T extends Fruit> extends ComboBox {

    @Autowired
    private JpaRepository<T, Integer> repository;
    ...
}

public class FruitMarket {

    @Autowired
    FruitComboBox<Apple> appleCombobox; // Apple extends Fruit

    @Autowired
    FruitComboBox<Orange> orangeCombobox; // Orange extends Fruit

    ...
}
```

Also I have two repositories

```
@Repository
public interface AppleRepository extends JpaRepository<Apple, Integer> {
}

@Repository
public interface OrangeRepository extends JpaRepository<Orange, Integer> {
}
```

I suppose that the generic repository from FruitComboBox should be resolved as one of two existing repositories according it's T, and autowired by Spring.

The **NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: expected single matching bean but found 2** occurs at runtime (not at start of application). So I supposed that at runtime all the types are defined and Spring has known what concrete type is T.

Comment: Any progress on this? I've got a similar problem and to me, it sounds like a bug!

Answer (score 0):

Spring data needs to know at the bootstrap time the the entity the repository represents. That means you can not leave it with `Generic Parameter` during autowiring.

Create a separate interface like below.

```
@Repository
public interface MyGenericRepository<T> extends JpaRepository<T, Integer>{

}
```

Now you should be able to autowire it with a definite type (not generic type). This is as generic as it gets.

```
@Autowired
private MyGenericRepository<Apple, Integer> repository;
```

**Above can not be left with generic parameter.**

Reference http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.5.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

Also try to use `Long` for the ID's.

Comment: Thanks, but I investigate the possibilities for autowiring of the repository which is actually exist. I gave a more precise definition, please see the question